# postgrator: not found while migrating postgresql database

Tags: database, express, heroku, migration, migrate

Error:

```
$ heroku run npm run migrate
Running npm run migrate on ⬢ shelly-moth-73910... up, run.3979 (Free)      

> noteful-app-server@1.0.0 migrate /app
> postgrator --config postgrator-config.js

sh: 1: postgrator: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! noteful-app-server@1.0.0 migrate: `postgrator --config postgrator-config.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the noteful-app-server@1.0.0 migrate script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-09-06T07_52_36_217Z-debug.log
```

postgrator-cli version 4.0.0 is installed on repo, running `npm list postgrator-cli` tells me that. But after I push to heroku it's as though postgrator doesn't exist. `heroku run npm install postgrator-cli` and other such commands don't change, and `heroku run npm list postgrator-cli` returns:

```
$ heroku run npm list postgrator-cli
Running npm list postgrator-cli on ⬢ rocky-garden-73910... up, run.7024 (Free)
noteful-app-server@1.0.0 /app
`-- (empty)
```

Here's my `postgrator-config.js`

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  'migrationsDirectory': 'migrations',
  'driver': 'pg',
  'connectionString':
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'
      ? process.env.TEST_DATABASE_URL
      : process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  'ssl': !!process.env.SSL,
};
```

Procfile contains `web: node src/server.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same error.

In my `package.json` I found that it was in my `"devDependencies"`, not my `"dependencies"`.

When I first installed it, I ran `npm i postgrator-cli -D`, making it a development dependency. When I tried installing it again without the `-D` it didn't do anything, so I **deleted it from my** `package.json`.

Then, I ran `npm i postgrator-cli` and checked my `package.json` and found that it was in my `dependencies`. I git added, committed, and pushed to heroku and then I ran `heroku run npm run migrate` -  it worked!

Comment: thank you for this, exactly what my problem was. And the only place online its been asked!